# Изменение Seekbar'a

Tags: java, android

Как изменить (или как называется) синюю часть у Seekbar'a указанного на рисунке слева от круга?

[image: Seekbar]

Comment: Посмотрите ответы тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar

Comment: Напишите это в ответ, наверняка многим полезно будет

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов задания (Создадим отдельный файл style.xml в папке drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
            <gradient android:useLevel="true"
                      android:startColor="#441144" // Здесь задаётся цвет
                      android:endColor="#454455"/> // Здесь задаётся цвет
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

А в элементе SeekBar: `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style"`